# garbage output after whitespace removing

Tags: c, string, algorithm, removing-whitespace

i've this code:

```
     int i =0;
  char * str = "ar   bitrary             whitespace";

  int whitespace=0,index;
  for(index = 0;index < strlen(str);index++)
    {
      if(isspace(str[index]) != 0)
    {
      whitespace++;
    }
    }


  char * tmp = (char *)calloc(strlen(str)-whitespace +1,sizeof(char));

  memset(tmp,'\0',strlen(tmp)+1);

  while(i < strlen(str))
    {
      if(isspace(str[i]) != 0)
    {
      i++;
      continue;
    }else if(isspace(str[i]) == 0)
    {

      strcat(tmp,&str[i]);
      i++;
    }

    }


  printf("\nnew string is: %s \n",tmp);
```

the problem is that the output is a string without the whitespace removed + some garbage character.
I've used memset to null terminate tmp,is there the problem?

Comment: Garbage after a string sounds like you missing a string terminator.

Comment: http://onlinegdb.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the source string could be calculated before this loop

```
for(index = 0;index < strlen(str);index++)
```

Otherwise if the code will not be optimized the function `strlen` will be called for each iteration of the loop. In fact using of the function is redundant for such a task.

This statement

```
memset(tmp,'\0',strlen(tmp)+1);
```

does not make sense because the call of `calloc` already initialized the memory with zeroes.

This statement

```
strcat(tmp,&str[i]);
```

also copies blanks from the source string after the position `i`. So it can write beyond the memory allocated for the array pointed to by the pointer `tmp`.

You can write a separate function that can look as it is shown in this demonstrative program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * remove_blanks( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    const char *p = s;

    do
    {
        if ( !isspace( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++n;
    } while ( *p++ );

    char *t = malloc( n );

    if ( t )
    {
        char *q = t;
        p = s;

        do
        {
            if ( !isspace( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) *q++ = *p;
        } while ( *p++ );
    }

    return t;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char * str = "ar   bitrary             whitespace";

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", str );

    char *t = remove_blanks( str );

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", t );

    free( t );
}
```

The program output is

```
"ar   bitrary             whitespace"
"arbitrarywhitespace"
```

Comment: Thanks,I'm trying to understand a couple of things: when you in the beginning say that the "strlen" in the for loop was redundant,could that be solved like "int ln = strlen(str)" and than using ln as upper limit for the loop?(avoiding like this the continuous call to strlen). Second things: the cast to unsigned character is really necessary? Third things: in the do-while loop as the argument of the while you use "*p++" and then in the isspace inside the loop you write "*p" as the argument, but *p don't indicate only to the first element of the string? Sorry for the questions,but I'm learning.

Comment: @Collapsed You can calculate the length either before the loop or in the part of the first expression of the for statement. If some characters can have negative values then it is necessary to cast to unsigned char. In the do while loop there is access to each character of the original string using the pointer p. So it must be increased to point each character sequentially and this is done in the condition of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I will not read your question, you overwrite the `'\0'` terminator for sure.

Now that I read your question, it looks like you need to understand strings and arrays better,

1. Don't ever write `while (i < strlen(str))`
2. Don't use `strcat()` for adding a single character, you apparently did overwrite the `'\0'` there. Furthermore, don't ever use `strcat()` for concatenating more than to pieces of a string.

Also notable,

- You `memset()` after `calloc()` which already initialized to `0`. That means that you are enforcing something that is not necessary, and trying it twice as if it failed the first time which I can guarantee it didn't.

  In fact, since you have used `calloc()` and all bytes pointed to by `tmp` are `0` then `strlen(tmp)` will return `0`, thus your `memset()` is equivalent to

  ```
  tmp[0] = '\0';
  ```

  and you REALLY don't need initialize `tmp` except when you finally copy the actual bytes from `str`.

I always advice against `calloc()` for strings, because

1. You don't really need to initialize something twice.
2. You should be sure your code does take the terminating `'\0'` into account and not simply assume that it's there because you `calloc()`ed. That is a bug that you just hide with `calloc()` but it shows up at some point.

Try this and see if you can understand the reasons for my changes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int whitespace;
    int length;
    char *str = "ar   bitrary             whitespace";
    char *tmp;

    whitespace = 0;
    for (length = 0; str[length] != '\0'; ++length) {
        if (isspace(str[length]) != 0) {
            whitespace++;
        }
    }
    tmp = malloc(length - whitespace + 1);
    if (tmp == NULL)
        return -1;
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (isspace(str[i]) != 0)
            continue;
        tmp[j++] = str[i];
    }
    tmp[length - whitespace] = '\0';
    printf("new string is: %s\n",tmp);

    free(tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for having answered. What is the reason why i don't have to write "while(i < strlen(str))" ? After everything I've to enforce the '\0' termination as you did(talking about the general case of working with strings)?

Comment: the strlen function will take time and spac. when you write `while(strlen(str))` the loop will go to the function every time until the loop will end.  when you write `int l=strlen(str)` before and use l you will call strlen only once.

Comment: @Collapsed Unlike in PHP where it's common to see `strlen()` in a loop control, in c it's not a good idea because the length is not stored anywhere. So every time you call it, it counts characters one by  one. The same goes for `strcat()`. Knowing the length of a string whose length will not change during the execution is a nice advantage in c that you can use for improving performance.

Answer (score 1):

this is your problem

```
 memset(tmp,'\0',strlen(tmp)+1);
```

`strlen(tmp)` works by looking for `'\0'` in `tmp`, you have a chicken and egg situation here.

You should not be doing a memset any way, just tack on a `'\0'` when you fnish copying

And dont use `strcat`, instead maintain a pointer to `tmp` and just do `*p = str[i]` then increment `p`

Comment: I don't understand, are you implying that there is no `0` terminator or that `memset()` only sets the first byte to `0`?